# How to disable text selection on richview in innosetup?

Tags: inno-setup, rtf, richtext

I have some problem, I got code like below and its working fine, but the problem is that I would like to disable text selection (links in the text must be clickable), I have tried some solutions but none works, tried also

property HideSelection: Boolean; read write;

but the text can still be selected.

```
[Code]

var
  Page: TWizardPage;

procedure CreateTheWizardPages;
var
  RichViewer1 : TRichEditViewer;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpReady, 'Custom', 'Page');

  RichViewer1 := TRichEditViewer.Create(Page);
  RichViewer1.Left := 0;
  RichViewer1.Top := 30;
  RichViewer1.width:=400;
  RichViewer1.WordWrap := True;
  RichViewer1.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  RichViewer1.TabStop := False;
  RichViewer1.ReadOnly := True;
  RichViewer1.Parent := Page.Surface;
  RichViewer1.ParentColor := true; 
  RichViewer1.RTFText :=  '{\rtf1 ' +
    '{\colortbl ;\red238\green0\blue0;}' +
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ' +
    '{\b {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://www.example.com/" }}' +
    '{\fldrslt{\cf1 CLICK_HERE\cf0 }}}} ' +
    'consectetur adipiscing elit.}';
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin 
  CreateTheWizardPages;
end;
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you want to disable text selection?

Comment: hmm, this is required by someone I work with.

Comment: That does not really answer my question.

Comment: I got long text which I want to put in custom wizard page, but the problem is that this text need contain clickable hyperlinks so I'm using for this TRichEditViewer.... I cannot use TNewStaticText (text selection disabled) because I wouldn't be able to put there clickable hyperlinks.

Comment: I do not see how does this answer, why you want to prevent the text selection.

Comment: I cannot explain it better , sorry .. I just want prevent text selection in TRichEditViewer if its possible, If you know any method how to do this I would be very gratefull. thank you so much.

Comment: I have the same question. What is the point in disabling text selection? I would personally find that very annoying, and doesn't actually stop anyone from simply retyping what they want to copy anyway.

Comment: Very weird, why everyone is asking why he wants to change it. Me personally don't like to have the cursor changing to the I-beam pointer, because that could make users think they could enter something there, even it is just a text.